# loading different pages in Iframe on button click, button is in main page

Tags: asp.net, .net, iframe, server-side

I have a back and next buttons and Iframe in main page.

On pressing next button next pages (which are forms to take input) are displayed in Iframe from server side.

I want to save data of current page  in DB and then load 2nd page in Iframe. On clicking again save data of Page2 in DB and then load 3rd page in Iframe.

Similarly if user clicks back button he should get data of previous page.

Please suggest me how it can be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To chane iframe src just use JS

```
function changeFrm(NewSrc){
document.getElementById('YOUR IFRAME ID').src=NewSrc;
};
```

And in your button add `onClick="ChangeFrm('NEW SOURCE');"`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Luis,

But how to save data of current page before loading 2nd page ?

Comment: So you don't have to do a lot of buttons? You can use `$_GET` variables if you are using php, and define an ID for each one, or `$_SESSIONS` also under PHP.